# Как задать width spinner программно?

Tags: android, java

Как можно задать ширину или высоту spinner программно из java?

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_r);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setPrompt("Список");
    spinner.setSelection(1);
    setContentView(spinner);
```

[Изображение как у меня есть](http://savepic.net/2733315.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо писать собственный класс наследник от `Spinner` и перегружать метод `Spinner.onMeasure()`

Только надо быть очень аккуратным и внимательно прочтите [документацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)). Метод капризный и запросто можно вылететь по экспешну.